# Linux named fifo non-blocking read select returns bogus read_fds

Tags: c, linux, select, named-pipes, nonblocking

Similar to the [problem asked a while ago on kernel 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592039/using-fifo-open-in-non-blocking-mode-with-select), but I'm seeing it on 4.9.37. 
The named fifo is created with `mkfifo -m 0666`. On the read side it is opened with

```
int fd = open(FIFO_NAME, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

The resulting `fd` is passed into a call to `select()`. Everything works ok, till I run `echo >> <fifo-name>`.

Now the `fd` appears in the `read_fds` after the `select()` returns. A `read()` on the `fd` will return one byte of data. So far so good.

The next time when `select()` is called and it returns, the `fd` still appears in the `read_fds`, but `read()` will always return zero meaning with no data. Effectively the read side would consume 100% of the processor capacity. This is exactly the same problem as observed by the referenced question.

Has anybody seen the same issue? And how can it be resolved or worked-around properly?

I've figured out if I close the read end of the fifo, and re-open it again, it will work properly. This probably is ok because we are not sending a lot of data. Though this is not a nice or general work-around.

Comment: saw an article about race conditions. will see whether something would be related: https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Pipes%2C-Part-2%3A-Pipe-programming-secrets#race-condition-with-named-pipes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, because the end-of-input case causes a `read()` to not block; it returns 0 immediately.

If you look at [man 2 select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), it says clearly that a descriptor in `readfds` is set if a `read()` on that descriptor would not block (at the time of the `select()` call).

If you used [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), it too would immediately return with `POLLHUP` in `revents`.

---

As OP notes, the correct workaround is to reopen the FIFO.

Because the Linux kernel maintains exactly one internal pipe object to represent  each open FIFO (see [man 7 fifo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) and [man 7 pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)), the robust approach in Linux is to open another descriptor to the FIFO whenever an end of input is encountered (`read()` returning 0), and close the original. During the time when *both* descriptors are open, they refer to the same kernel pipe object, so there is no race window or risk of data loss.

In pseudo-C:

```
fifoflags = O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK;
fifofd = open(fifoname, fifoflags);
if (fifofd == -1) {
    /* Error checking */
}

/* ... */

/* select() readfds contains fifofd, or
   poll() returns POLLIN for fifofd: */

    n = read(fifofd, buffer, sizeof buffer)
    if (!n) {
        int tempfd;

        tempfd = open(fifopath, fifoflags);
        if (tempfd == -1) {
            const int cause = errno;
            close(fifofd);

            /* Error handling */

        }
        close(fifofd);
        fifofd = tempfd;

        /* A writer has closed the FIFO. */

    } else
        /* Handling for the other read() result cases */
```

The file descriptor allocation policy in Linux is such that `tempfd` will be the lowest-numbered free descriptor.

On my system (Core i5-7200U laptop), reopening a FIFO in this way takes less than 1.5 µs. That is, it can be done about 680,000 times a second. I do not think this reopening is a bottleneck for any sensible scenario, even on low-powered embedded Linux machines.

Comment: Hi, If I open the write end of the fifo again, the read end would change back to normal. Is this also a specified behavior? I used `sleep 5 >> FIFONAME`, and seeing the read end is not getting readfds and zero from read() for 5 seconds.

Comment: @minghua: Yes, that is as expected as well. When another (or the same) writer opens the fifo for writing again, it changes the read end state (from end-of-stream), because now there is a possibility of new data. It is after (the last) writer has closed the fifo, and before a (first) new writer opens it, that the read end is in the end-of-input state. The only way the read end can "reset" that state is by reopening the fifo (which is not computationally expensive at all). That state is also reset by another writer opening the fifo for writing. Does that clear it up?